# Unexpected variables in arguments[] when passing a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, apply

I have two files in a folder - `index.js` and `util.js` with their code base as follows

Util.js

```
let obj = {}
obj.sendTransaction = () => {
  console.log(arguments);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // try {
    //   let data = ethFunction.call()
    //   resolve(data)
    // } catch (e) {
    //   reject(e)
    // }
  });
}
module.exports = obj
```

In `Index.js`, if I pass arguments to `addNewParticipant` or its variation then they do not turn up in the arguments object in `util.js`, for instance

```
const addNewParticipant = (foo, bar) => {
  var ethFunction = myContract.addParticipant.sendTransaction
  console.log(ethFunction);
  EthUtil.sendTransaction()
}

const addNewParticipantTwo = (foo, bar) => {
  var ethFunction = myContract.addParticipant.sendTransaction
  console.log(ethFunction);
  EthUtil.sendTransaction(ethFunction, foo, bar)
}
```

and call it such `addNewParticpant(1, 2)` and , `addNewParticpantNew(1, 2)` the numbers 1 and 2 do not show up in the arguments object in the util function. In fact, the arguments object remains the same, 4 inputs describing some functions and files in `node_modules` including `Bluebird` and a reference to `index.js` itself

---

My final aim is to

1. Pass a function from `index.js` to `util.js`
2. Pass along unknown number of variables
3. Call the passed function and apply the unknown number of variables to it
4. Wrap the whole thing in a promise and do some data validation

Ideally `arguments[0]` would represent a function I would pass and the other would be the values. I would then use

```
var result = arguments[0].apply(null, Array().slice.call(arguments, 1));
```

If it helps, the function I want to pass has an optional callback feature

Comment: fat arrows don't have an own `this` or `arguments` object. If you want these, you'll have to use "regular functions". or you use a [rest parameter](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `obj.sendTransaction = (fn, ...args) => { console.log(fn, args) }`

Comment: And please stop spamming tags, this question has nothing to do with nodejs, prototype or prototypejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, fat arrows don't have their own `this` or `arguments` objects. The `arguments` object you're logging is from the function created by the module loader, and its passed arguments.

You can either use a "regular function", or in this case, you can use a [...rest parameter](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

And, avoid the Deferred antipattern.

```
//first a little utility that might be handy in different places:
//casts/converts a value to a promise,
//unlike Promise.resolve, passed functions are executed
var promise = function(value){
    return typeof value === "function"?
        this.then( value ):
        Promise.resolve( value );
}.bind( Promise.resolve() );

module.exports = {
    sendTransaction(fn, ...args){
        return promise(() => fn.apply(null, args));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to a regular function and used apply. Just finishing off all the tests but the first few passed. As per this http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html , Deferred anti-pattern is when `superfluous wrapping` is used instead of simply returning the initial Promise itself. I am a bit new to Promises so not sure why my code is an anti-pattern. If you could please point it out, thanks

Comment: @VarunAgarwal because of the verbose and imo unnecessary `new Promise()` wrapper while every `resolvedPromise.then()` does the job; even handling the reject part.  But this is just a minor point.